# Book about the Logos Cube

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a book where a child (or multiple children) goes into some parallel world. There is an important cube called the Logos Cube, hidden in this world.

Eventually the child finds the cube hidden in something like a window ornament.

Could someone identify this book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's [The Mansion in the Mist](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BuPiD23t5OIC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=logos) by John Bellairs.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be correct. I recall the trunk too.

Comment: @Manishearth: All down to my vast knowledge of fictional science :-)